# differentiate between the subscript(s) and coefficient(s) that make up the chemical formula for sulfuric acid, 2H2SO4

Tags: notation

Im confuse on whats the question is asking.
differentiate between the subscript(s) and coefficient(s) that make up the chemical formula for sulfuric acid, $\ce{2H2SO4}$.

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE. This might be related :) [Should chem.SE use Georgia font?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4302/544)

Comment: Do you know in general, what subscripts and coefficients in a chemical formula are? Do you have problems with both terms or only one of them (which one?)?

Comment: @mykhal I don't it matters much for someone who clearly doesn't know formula for sulphuric acid...

Answer (score 4):

Subscripts and Coefficients both show the quantity of elements. The difference is that subscripts show the number of atoms *in* a molecule, while coefficients show the *number of molecules* there are. Also, subscripts are placed immediately after the atom it describes: $\ce{H2O}$. the 2 is describing the number of H atoms there are. $\ce{3H2O}$ is 3 molecules of $\ce{H2O}$.